# Magento2- How to remove last name

Tags: magento2

in magento2 , How to remove last name ,Only first name is retained.

I see magento1.x have such a plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can run below query in your database for set lastname as optional for customer.

> UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code =
>   'lastname' and `entity_type_id` = 1

Go to below file where you can find class field-name-lastname in code. delete complete this div for last name.

```
vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

You can copy the file to your custom theme or module and change accordingly.
Not recommended to change directly in core module.

Comment: 2.1.2 ,  I did not find this directory vendor/magento/module-customer

Comment: I just downloaded and able to see Magento-CE-2.1.2_sample_data-2016-10-11-11-27-51\vendor\magento\module-customer\view

Comment: hello, I download new version magento 2.12, I looked module-customer/view/nam.phtml/ .  I want to ask you ,  The checkout page, how to remove last name field .

Comment: hello,how to remove The billing address shipping address  last name ?

Comment: Hi krishna, i need to remove it, only in checkout page

Comment: if you are find  to a solution  for this, please shared

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you want to remove last name so first you need to update table column for lastname in "eav_attribute".

Run query which is given below.

**UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname' and entity_type_id = 1**

**2)** Then override the file from the vendor folder to your theme on the given path that i have given below.

vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml

to

app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Customer\templates\widget\name.phtml

Go to your override file where you can find the class "field-name-lastname" in the code. delete or comment completely this div for last name.

**Note :** If you have already overridden this file in your theme so just no need to override it again you can just update it.